# Solvability of finite factorized groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G = AB$ be a finite factorized group. That is, $A \leq G$, $B \leq G$ and for each $g \in G$ there are $a \in A$ and $b \in B$ such that $g = ab$.

I'm looking for results which guarantee the solvability of $G$ given some restrictions on $A$ and $B$. Here's a list of the results I'm aware of:

> **Theorem 1** (Huppert, Itô 1954): If $A$ is supersolvable and $B$ is cyclic of odd order, then $G$ is solvable.
>
> **Theorem 2** (Itô 1955): If $A$ and $B$ are abelian, then $G$ is solvable (of derived length at most two).
>
> **Theorem 3** (Wielandt 1958, Kegel 1961): If $A$ and $B$ are nilpotent, then $G$ is solvable.
>
> **Theorem 4** (Kazarin 1979): If $A$ and $B$ have nilpotent subgroups of index at most two, then $G$ is solvable.
>
> **Theorem 5** (Carocca 2002): If $A$ is $2$-nilpotent and $B$ is nilpotent of odd order, then $G$ is solvable.

Please correct me if there are errors in the above list. I'm looking for other results in this direction. I discovered that many mathematicians who have contributed to solving this problem, write papers also in Russian or German, which made the search even more difficult.

If we restrict the structure of one of the subgroups more (say, $A$ is abelian / cyclic / of certain order), is it possible to loosen the restrictions on $B$ and still get solvability for $G$?

Comment: Not an error, but, although it is implied by some of the others stated results, Burnside's proof that a group of order $p^{a}q^{b}$ is solvable ($p,q$ distinct primes) deserves a mention, since it was undoubtedly an inspiration for later results of this type.

Comment: Another question which might be worth a mention is the conjecture ( of Szep(?)) that a finite group of the form $C_{G}(a)C_{G}(b)$ for non-identity $a,b$ can't be non-Abelian simple. I presume this is now resolved.

Comment: I considered putting both theorems you mentioned to the list as well. :) http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0021869387901074 Here's a proof of the conjecture from 1987.

Comment: I am not sure why you want only to consider finite groups, but Theorem 2 is true for all groups, whereas I think Theorem 3 is still an open problem for infinite groups.

Comment: The motivation behind this question just happens to be a finite factorized group, where one factor is either abelian (of even order) or $2$-nilpotent. That's why finite.

Comment: Would it help if the factors had trivial intersection? I remember seeing some papers about the case where the factors had coprime orders, but that's too much.